# How to fetch SQLite data starting with "%" (percent sign)?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a database in which I have few tables. I have a table which contains a column containing tag names and tag IDs. There is a situation where I have tag name and I want the tag IDs for all those tags whose tag names start with the input text.

The problem is that when I am hitting database for tag name "%", it is returning all the rows of that table. But I need only those rows which contains tag names starting with the the input text (which in this case is starting with the "%" symbol).

Example:

```
TagName
-------
abc
%test_tag
def
```

the result should be "%test_tag" if I search for "%".

Currently, the query which I am using is

```
SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE TagName like '"+tagName+" %'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android SQLite LIKE escape wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830034/android-sqlite-like-escape-wildcard)

Comment: I already tried ESCAPE keyword  but no success

Answer (score 5):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830034/android-sqlite-like-escape-wildcard), you need to use the ESCAPE keyword. If it didn't work for you, please post your attempt. I have successfully used the following query, which matches `https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s`:

```
SELECT * FROM moz_places WHERE url LIKE '%de.wikipedia.org%\%s' ESCAPE '\'
```

Basically, pick an escape character (e.g. `:`), and replace any instance of `%` with `:%` (or whatever character you picked). If the escape character itself can appear in searches, replace each occurrence with the escape character with two escape characters. Pseudocode:

```
search = '%test'
search = search.replace(':', '::')
search = search.replace('%', ':%')

query = "SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE TagName like '"+search+"%'"
```

Note that I removed a space before your % sign, that might have been the issue. Also, **don't build SQL queries by concatenating strings** unless you want SQL injection. Use prepared statements.

(I know the question is old, but others will Google it and deserve an answer.)

Comment: For future reference: For multiple statements, ESCAPE needs to be added to each one.
"Where column_a LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\' or column_b LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'" For example.

Answer (score 0):

% is a reserved operator for sql its usage : `LIKE %ong%` will get the rows including "ong" string in it for example : "Long".

You have to use an escape case for "%" character. I don't know how to escape % character but im sure you can find it in a short googling.

Comment: there should be another way to escape  like single quote. you can escape single quote by using it twice like :  ' Ercan''s'. isn't there another way to escape % like this?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to escape % like this

Comment: Can you replace % with another special character instead? even a word can do the job: "SELECT * FROM Tags where TagName LIKE 'POTATO%'"

Answer (score 0):

The idea from [the accepted answer on other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063424/2821954) is to use `BETWEEN` keyword instead, for query starting/ending with `LIKE`'s wildcard keywords (e.g. `%` and `_`).

Try something like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Tags";
if(tagName.startsWith("%")) {
    query += " WHERE TagName BETWEEN " + tagName + " AND " + tagName + "z";
} else {
    query += " WHERE TagName LIKE '" + tagName + "%'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **replace** function in this case:

```
select *
from Tags where replace(TagName,'%','@')like '@%'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from Tags where Tagname like '%"+tagname+"'
```

This will do the job

Comment: This will return all the rows if tagname is "%"

Comment: yes It will. But the best practice should be not to add % in tagname. try something else like #  or @. Why you want % in name. Anything related to it

Comment: I cannot prevent "% from getting used as it is customer's requirement.